# Delete a row by custom field in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, model, crud

I am facing an issue with deleting rows from table by custom field.

Below my database table

```
link_id | quote_id  | giftcard_value | giftcard | redeemed_at
--------------------------------------------------------------
10000   | 20000     | 450            | XSERTTY3 | 2015-12-01
10001   | 20000     | 600            | DSFDTTY3 | 2015-12-01
```

I need to delete all the entries by quote_is.

My code is like this

```
Mage::getModel('xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx')->load($quote->getId(),'quote_id')->delete();
```

But its  working for one entry, but not working for may entries. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to load the entire entities it is not optimal in terms of performance.

You should use collections instead:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx_collection')->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $quote->getId());
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $item->delete();
}
```

Comment: Its giving PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method xxxx_xxxx_Model_Resource_xxxxx_Collection::delete()

Comment: @duke see my update

Answer (score 3):

Here `->load($quote->getId(),'quote_id')` may return multiple rows, so if you do `->delete()` on this collection, ONLY first row will be deleted.

You should loop through the collection for deleting all fetched rows :

```
$items = Mage::getModel('xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx')->load($quote->getId(),'quote_id');
foreach($items as $item){
    $item->delete();
}
```

**Otherwise**, I have heared about `deleteAll` method (BUT I've never tried it) :

```
//Not sure, but Give it a try
Mage::getModel('xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx')->load($quote->getId(),'quote_id')->deleteAll();
```